# Не удается включить .cshtml файл как ссылку

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Есть 2 проекта ASP.NET MVC5. Некоторые `представления` являются одинаковыми, поэтому решил держать их в одном файле и в проектах ссылаться на них (Add existing item -> Add as link).

Казалось бы, все очень просто, но такие включенные ссылкой файлы `представлений`, как будто отсутствуют в проекте: по всему файлу ошибки, начиная с `@model The name model is does not exist in the current context`, а при запуске вовсе пишет, что view not found.

В file properties файла выставил значения `Brouse to URL`, `Build action` по аналогии с другими.

Можно ли включать .cshtml ссылкой и как это делать?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под словами "включенные ссылкой файлы"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC625712.png

Comment: о, хороший вопрос, вечером отвечу. Кратко: так нельзя делать.

Comment: [похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136128/asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-add-views-scripts-and-content-files-as-links-in-order-to)

Comment: @Grundy нашел решение, что бы при запуске работало: http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx. Но VS, как и ожидалось, в редакторе показывает ошибки в файле.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ваше решение такое же?

Comment: @Ildar нет, там глупость написана

Comment: @Grundy вот только тот "похожий вопрос" остался без ответа

Comment: @PavelMayorov, разве? как минимум workaround они предложили, ну и тоже сказали, что нельзя :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, кстати :-) вечер был, кое-кто собирался ответ написать :-)

Comment: @Grundy а вы по ссылке переходили? У меня не открывается. И не только у меня, судя по комментариям.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, по какой ссылке?

Comment: @Grundy на workaround в принятом ответе

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а, не, мне больше ответ Darin Dimitrov понравился

Comment: @Grundy вы про CDN? Это не решает проблему неработоспособности на машине разработчика.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ага

Comment: @Grundy что - "ага"? Тот ответ, как выяснилось, вообще никакую проблему не решает, потому что при публикации ссылки работают! Он вам еще нравится? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ага, про CDN :-) он ж там и пишет: _не вы не можете_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что есть 3 разных агента, которым нужны эти виды - и все они по-разному настраиваются. В Microsoft проделали большую работу, чтобы они все работали с одними и теми же файлами - но вот файлов-ссылок не предусмотрели.

Придется вам все объяснять им самостоятельно. И так, по порядку.

### 1. Редактор Visual Studio

Редактор Visual Studio попросту не умеет редактировать файлы за пределами папки проекта. Вам надо сделать отдельный проект для общих файлов - и открывать эти файлы только в нем.

### 2. Локальный сервер

Локальный сервер хостит файлы непосредственно из папки проекта, не читая файл проекта. Поскольку файла на этом месте реально нет - происходит ошибка.

Чтобы "обучить" сервер отдавать файлы исходя из их наличия в проекте, а не на диске - можно использовать вот такой класс:

```
class ProjectFileProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{
    private readonly string applicationVirtualPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;
    private readonly string applicationPhysicalPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ProjectFile> projectFiles;

    public ProjectFileProvider(string projectFile)
    {
        if (!applicationVirtualPath.EndsWith("/"))
            applicationVirtualPath = applicationVirtualPath + "/";

        var project = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(applicationPhysicalPath, projectFile));
        var ns = project.Root.Name.Namespace;

        projectFiles = (from item in project.Root.Elements(ns + "ItemGroup").Elements()
                        where item.Name.LocalName == "None" || item.Name.LocalName == "Content"
                        let virtualPath = (string)item.Element(ns + "Link") ?? (string)item.Attribute("Include")
                        let physicalPath = (string)item.Attribute("Include")
                        select new ProjectFile(applicationVirtualPath + virtualPath, Path.Combine(applicationPhysicalPath, physicalPath)))
                        .ToDictionary(file => file.VirtualPath, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (virtualPath.StartsWith("~/"))
            virtualPath = applicationVirtualPath + virtualPath.Substring(2);

        ProjectFile file;
        projectFiles.TryGetValue(virtualPath, out file);
        return file;
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (virtualPath.StartsWith("~/"))
            virtualPath = applicationVirtualPath + virtualPath.Substring(2);

        return projectFiles.ContainsKey(virtualPath);
    }

    public override string GetFileHash(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies)
    {
        long hash = 0;

        foreach (string filepath in virtualPathDependencies)
        unchecked {
            hash = hash * 31 + filepath.GetHashCode();

            var file = GetFile(filepath) as ProjectFile;
            if (file != null)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + file.GetFileInfo().LastWriteTimeUtc.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        return hash.ToString("x");
    }

    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        var files = virtualPathDependencies.Cast<string>().Select(GetFile).Cast<ProjectFile>().Where(file => file != null).Select(file => file.PhysicalPath).ToArray();
        return new CacheDependency(files, utcStart);
    }
}

private class ProjectFile : VirtualFile
{
    public ProjectFile(string virtualPath, string physicalPath) : base(virtualPath)
    {
        PhysicalPath = physicalPath;
    }

    public string PhysicalPath { get; }

    public override Stream Open() => File.OpenRead(PhysicalPath);

    public FileInfo GetFileInfo() => new FileInfo(PhysicalPath);
}
```

Подключается он просто:

```
if (HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists("~/Foo.csproj"))
    HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new ProjectFileProvider("Foo.csproj"));
```

**Важное замечание** Этот способ работает только для тех файлов, которые нужны ASP.NET. То есть сюда попадают всяческие .aspx, .cshtml, .svc и прочие подобные файлы.

А вот скрипты и картинки отдаются IIS напрямую, поэтому к ним подобный трюк не применим.

### 3. Публикация

При публикации вашего приложения система сборки собирает все файлы вместе, для передачи их на сервер. Здесь я хотел написать как редактировать вручную csproj-файл для встраивания в publication pipeline - но внезапно оказалось что система публикации уже поддерживает ссылки.

Но тут есть тонкость, связанная с прошлым пунктом. Дело в том, что файл проекта не публикуется. Именно поэтому в прошлом пункте я ставил проверку на его наличие.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, 2. Локальный сервер - это тот случай, решение которого предложено http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx ?

Comment: @Ildar да, но там оно кривое (при использовании системы контроля версий в ней будет появляться мусор; плюс изменения в файлах перестанут подхватываться на лету).

Comment: п.2 работает, действительно удобно, чем файлы копировать при перестройке, как указано в приведённой мной ссылке. С п.1 пока придётся смириться